# Setting random effect and nested random effect correctly in glmmTMB model

Tags: mixed-model, random-variable, biostatistics, nested-data, glmmtmb

I have been having trouble fitting my data of seedsets of flowers. I have gathered data from seven flowering species in four different elevations. Not all the species appear in every elevation and the elevations are not equally spaced from each other. I would like to see if there is a trend in seedsets based on elevation, with "species" as a random factor (the seven species were chosen randomly, the criteria was that they should grow in at least two of the elevations).

I also have data about the plant individuals, meaning that I know from which plant individual a seedset was taken. In my dataset, there are plant individuals which produced multiple seedset (I treated several flowers in case that some would get eaten/die/etc.) So I would also like to eliminate the possibility of pseudoreplications and nestedness in this case.

My question is, if I want to see the effect of seedset on elevation, have species as a random factor but also want to consider that some individuals produced more than one seedset, would the correct formula look like this?

```r
model <- glmmTMB(seedset ~ elevation  + (1 | species) + 
                 (1 | species:plant.number), ziformula = ~ elevation, 
                 data = data, family = poisson)
```

I was under the impression that it would be ok like this, however I also decided to make a column in my data `new.plant.number`, where I changed all plant.numbers, so that they would be elevation specific. I did this by adding a certain number to the plant.number, in order to eliminate the possibility of having duplicate values for plant.number for any species.

```r
seed.indices <- seed.indices %>% mutate(new.plant.number = 
    case_when(elevation == 2300 ~ plant.number, 
              elevation == 2800 ~ plant.number + 49, 
              elevation == 3500 ~ plant.number + 99, 
              elevation == 4000 ~ plant.number + 149, 
              TRUE ~ plant.number))
```

Specifically, the code left species "1" plant.number "1" in elevation "2300" as is, however changed species "1" plant.number "1" in elevation "2800" to new.plant.number "50".

I decided to fit both the model with "(1 | species:plant.number)" and also "(1 | species:new.plant.number)", however I got different results for these models. This leads me to believe that I am misspecifying the model, or that I have some other error in my formula.

Comment: Hard to say since there is no reproducible example. Also these questions are not really on-topic here. My guess is that your `case_when` statement didn't create the same number of levels or clusters when compared to your original grouping variable. Maybe double check that.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me why this question is not on-topic? If it is the second part about the "new.plant.number", I simply added that in order to try to explain that I am not sure with the fit of my data. My main question was about if my formula is correct, considering the setup of my data. If the second part does not add value to the post, I can edit it out

Comment: So `plant.number` is an indicator variable intended to point to different plants. But these IDs are not unique in the dataset: there is a plant with ID 1 at elevation 2300 and also another plant with ID 1 at elevation 2800. It's a good idea to assign unique IDs to unique individuals, ie. not to re-use ID 1. I'd probably do something simple such as: `new.plant.number = paste0(elevation, "-", species, "-", plant.number)`. No need to know that there are 4 elevations are they are 2800, 2800, etc.

Comment: I'd guess you get different results with the two formulas because (unintentionally) there are plants at different elevation that have the same `plant.number`. The nesting `(1 | species) + (1 | species:plant.number) =  (1 | species/plant.number)` can only handle duplicate IDs across different species. (Not different elevations).

Comment: Finally, I would also consider whether `elevation` should be a factor (rather than assume a linear relationship in the model).

Comment: Hi @dipetkov, thanks for the replies. Since writing the original question, I have come to the conclusions which you mentioned. However, I am now confused about one another thing, should species and plant.number also be elevation specific or not? I do not think they should, but I am not sure. Currectly, I believe this to be the correct formula:
'model <- glmmTMB(seedset ~ elevation  + (1 | species) + 
                 (1 | plant.number), ziformula = ~ elevation, 
                 data = data, family = poisson)'

Comment: I ask this, because the the species repeat in different elevations and inevitably do do the plant.numbers. So as you suggest 'new.plant.number = paste0(elevation, "-", species, "-", plant.number)', should I not do a similar thing for species? Specifically, 'new.species = paste0(elevation, "-", species)' instead of using just "species".

Comment: Can you share the data? Or at least a dataset that has the same structure for species, plant.number and elevation with simulated/fake seedset. I'm not 100% sure what's the structure of your data (which is why I wrote a comment and not an answer).

Comment: structure(list(seedset = c(2L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 3L), elevation = c(2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 
2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2300L, 2800L, 2800L, 2800L, 2800L, 2800L, 
2800L, 3500L, 3500L, 3500L), species = c("purpureus", "purpureus", 
"inermis", "inermis", "inermis", "burtonii", "burtonii", "purpureus", 
"purpureus", "purpureus", "inermis", "inermis", "inermis", "purpureus", 
"burtonii", "burtonii"), plant.number = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

Comment: This is an example of how the dataset looks. Multiple elevations, within each elevation some species, but not all species in all elevations. Each species has a some plant.number specific to it, however it repeats between elevations and species. This can be solved with the formula you mentioned about making new.plant.number, so that the plant number have no duplicates (except the ones from the same plant in the same species in the same elevation). I am not sure if this is necessary to do also for "species"

Comment: Thanks for the data, it helps. Just to confirm (because I think I may have made a wrong assumption) -- does plant.number mean number of plants of that species, or is plant.number an ID (something like "the 1st purpureus on this elevation that I collected")? [So far I've assumed that plant.number is an ID.]

Comment: Sorry the confussion. plant.number is plant ID (specifically I had the plants numbered based on when I treated them, not collected them, but that is a minor difference). I treated multiple flowers on one plant individual when possible, because I expect high mortality rates. This is why I sometimes have multiple of the same elevation, species and plant.number, for example in the data provided multiple instances of elevation: 2300, species: inermis, plant.number: 1. I had two different seedset from two different treated flowers on the same plant individual, a psuedoreplication

Comment: Okay. This is what I would do: (1) Give the individual plants unique IDs (by hand; this is the most straightforward solution & guarantees things are correct). (2) Use the model `seedset ~ elevation  + (1 | species / plant.id)`; this formula expresses the intuition that (random) plants are nested within (random) species. PS: You can assign unique IDs with the method I suggested above `plant.id = paste0(elevation, "-", species, "-", plant.number)`. (I get 13 unique plants in the example dataset.) The model would recognize & deal with the fact there are multiple observations from some plants.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. However, I am still uncertain about one thing. Could you please help me understand why I should not do a similar thing with "species" as with "plant.id"? In other words, why does the "species" also not need to be elevation specific in the same way as plant.id, since the same species are in multiple elvations. Why do I not need to do something similar? 'species.id = paste0(elevation, "-", species)' and put that into the model? I think that this is mainly my misunderstanding of nestednes, random/crossed effects and the syntax for adressing these problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start by quoting relevant information provided in the comments:

> This is an example of how the dataset looks. plant.number is plant ID (specifically I had the plants numbered based on when I treated them, not collected them, but that is a minor difference). I treated multiple flowers on one plant individual when possible, because I expect high mortality rates. This is why I sometimes have multiple of the same elevation, species and plant.number, for example in the data provided multiple instances of elevation: 2300, species: inermis, plant.number: 1. I had two different seedset from two different treated flowers on the same plant individual, a pseudoreplication

```r
data
#>    seedset elevation   species plant.number
#> 1        0      2300  burtonii            1
#> 2        0      2300  burtonii            1
#> 3        0      3500  burtonii            1
#> 4        3      3500  burtonii            4
#> 5        0      2300   inermis            1
#> 6        5      2300   inermis            1
#> 7        2      2300   inermis            2
#> 8        2      2800   inermis            1
#> 9        0      2800   inermis            2
#> 10       0      2800   inermis            4
#> 11       2      2300 purpureus            1
#> 12       4      2300 purpureus            3
#> 13       0      2800 purpureus            1
#> 14       4      2800 purpureus            1
#> 15       5      2800 purpureus            2
#> 16      13      3500 purpureus            2
```

Given this information, I add a column `plant.id` to uniquely identify plants across the elevations. (I just discovered the handy [`dplyr::consecutive_id`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/consecutive_id.html) function to assign group ids to rows with the same value in one or more columns.)

```r
data |>
  mutate(
    plant.id = consecutive_id(elevation, species, plant.number)
  )
#>    seedset elevation   species plant.number plant.id
#> 1        0      2300  burtonii            1        1
#> 2        0      2300  burtonii            1        1
#> 3        0      3500  burtonii            1        2
#> 4        3      3500  burtonii            4        3
#> 5        0      2300   inermis            1        4
#> 6        5      2300   inermis            1        4
#> 7        2      2300   inermis            2        5
#> 8        2      2800   inermis            1        6
#> 9        0      2800   inermis            2        7
#> 10       0      2800   inermis            4        8
#> 11       2      2300 purpureus            1        9
#> 12       4      2300 purpureus            3       10
#> 13       0      2800 purpureus            1       11
#> 14       4      2800 purpureus            1       11
#> 15       5      2800 purpureus            2       12
#> 16      13      3500 purpureus            2       13
```

The `plant.number` column can now be dropped. As an aside, I suspect that non-consecutive `plant.number` means that a flower was treated but died and this information could be of interest in itself, eg. to investigate whether the mortality rate varies by elevation and/or species.

The question states that `species` is to be treated as a random factor because the seven species were randomly chosen. The individual plants were randomly chosen as well. So the random structure is "plants nested within species".

```r
m1 <- glmmTMB(
  seedset ~ elevation + (1 | species / plant.id),
  # The sample is not large enough to model zero-inflation.
  # ziformula = ~ elevation,
  family = poisson,
  data = data
)
```

Let's extract the random effects from the fitted model. Here we are not interested in the estimates (we are working with only a sample of the data) but in what the random effects represent.

```r
ranef(m1)
#> $`plant.id:species`
#>              (Intercept)
#> 1:burtonii   -0.24585008
#> 2:burtonii   -0.33057256
#> 3:burtonii    0.23505749
#> 4:inermis     0.43947808
#> 5:inermis     0.18659931
#> 6:inermis     0.05404257
#> 7:inermis    -0.33313993
#> 8:inermis    -0.33313993
#> 9:purpureus  -0.06814540
#> 10:purpureus  0.24836947
#> 11:purpureus -0.35289996
#> 12:purpureus  0.15879164
#> 13:purpureus  0.46953209
#> 
#> $species
#>           (Intercept)
#> burtonii  -0.61197697
#> inermis    0.02481162
#> purpureus  0.81685544
```

We have one random effect for each species and for each plant (nested within species). Intuitively, this makes sense because a species of plants can grow at different elevations but an individual plant grows at one particular spot, which is of course at one particular elevation.

It can be instructive to fit the model with `plant.number` instead of `plant.id` and look at the random effect estimates again. In that case, glmmTMB assumes — incorrectly — that the same plant can be observed at more than one elevation.

---

The OP has a follow-up question:

> Why does the "species" also not need to be elevation specific in the same way as plant.id, since the same species are in multiple elevations?

This could be a reasonable thing to do. It would have the consequence of modeling the random variability within species that is due to elevation *in addition to the fixed elevation effect*. It may help to fit that model and look at the variance components.

```r
m2 <- glmmTMB(
  seedset ~ elevation + (1 | species / elevation / plant.id),
  # ziformula = ~ elevation,
  family = poisson,
  data = data
)
```

```r
print(VarCorr(m1), comp = "Variance")
#> Conditional model:
#>  Groups           Name        Variance
#>  plant.id:species (Intercept) 0.27235 
#>  species          (Intercept) 0.48825

print(VarCorr(m2), comp = "Variance")
#> Conditional model:
#>  Groups                     Name        Variance
#>  plant.id:elevation:species (Intercept) 0.12200 
#>  elevation:species          (Intercept) 0.17988 
#>  species                    (Intercept) 0.50111
```

The "plant within species" variance is (approximately) decomposed into "elevation within species" and "plant within elevation within species" variance. This analysis of variance looks at an additional aspect of how the outcome varies with elevation that could complement the analysis of its fixed (ie. average across species) effect.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. The first part makes complete sense to me and I agree that it should be done in the way you mention, making the plant.id and using only that instead of the original plant.number. However, I am still confused as to the second part, in which you answer the question if I should not do the same for species.

Comment: First, I meant if I should create an individual id of species in each elevation. In the model version which you have written `(1|species/elevation/plant.id)`, wouldn't the model be assuming that elevation is nested within species instead of species in elevation? I would expect that it would have to be written as `(1|elevation/species/plant.id)`. Am I missunderstanding the syntax?

Comment: Secondly, you write that it might be a reasonable thing to do, fitting the species as nested within elevation, but by what measures do I then tell is the model is a good fit? My new problem is that although the AIC and BIC are slightly lower when I fit the model with `(1|species.id/plant.id)` (where `species.id=paste0(elevation,species)`) the model residual are much more dispersed (significantly, checking with package DHARMa) and it seems that the model is a worse fit than when I just fit the model only as `seedset ~ elevation + (1 | species / plant.id)`.

Comment: I don't think `elevation + (1|elevation/species/plant.id)` makes sense because `elevation` is already a fixed effect. More generally, `A + (1 | A)` doesn't make sense because the random component `(1 | A)` will explain variation away from the fixed component `A`.

Comment: I said it "could be a reasonable thing to do", not "definitely do this thing". If the model evaluation points to `elevation + (1 | species / plant.id)`, I say you go with this specification. You may be overthinking the random component a bit. The goal is to choose an appropriate form for the random effects, so that you get accurate std. errors for the fixed effects. Isn't the main interest the effect of elevation?

Comment: Just to be clear: I use elevation in consecutive_id(elevation, species, plant.number) not because I want to suggest that the random component should be (elevation / species / plant.number). I need to use elevation to assign unique ids to individual plants. It's always a good practice to assign unique ids to separate participants, students, plants, etc. Can save a lot of trouble later on.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments, they significantly helped me in understanding my data better!